# vqadmin "invalid language file" with google chrome

Tags: email, google-chrome

We have been running our qmail setup for awhile with no issues. One of our admins has moved to Google Chrome as his main browser and we have noticed something odd. No matter what, when he loads the vqadmin page it errors on him with simply `invalid language file`. Yet if he loads Firefox, Opera, Safari or **shudders** IE8 it works fine.

Searching google only results in 'Use IE' or 'Set english as your language in the browser'. A: I try to have people avoid IE if possible and B: There is no english option in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vqadmin looks for a language folder based on the browser language setting.
So find out in the web server logs what the browser is requesting.

eg

en
en-us
en-au 
...

Then create the appropriate language folder where vqadmin expects it and copy english over.
Translate if necessary.

Languages are in vqadmin/html, and are lower case.

My folder list looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1625 Aug 11  2010 br
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1740 Aug 11  2010 de
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1492 Aug 11  2010 en
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1492 Aug 11  2010 en-us
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1736 Aug 11  2010 es
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1757 Aug 11  2010 fi
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1671 Aug 11  2010 fr
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1719 Aug 11  2010 hu
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1637 Aug 11  2010 it
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1544 Aug 11  2010 ja
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1634 Aug 11  2010 nl
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1496 Aug 11  2010 pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1483 Aug 20  2009 zh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 1483 Aug 20  2009 zh-cn
```

eg, if I wanted to add Australian support to vqadmin, i might do

cp -rp en  en-au

and optionally change some of the spelling within that folder to Australian spelling standards.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome asks for en-US, but vqadmin doesn't translate the case to match what it knows as "en-us".

A quick fix is to cp or symlink vqadmin/html/en-us to vqadmin/html/en-US.